# Retrieve web service metadata having IP and port

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

All I have is IP address and port in private network where some web service is installed. There's no any documentation for this one. I don't have physical access to it. And I should work with it somehow.

What I tried already:
1) IP:portname in browser => ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

2) Tried to retrieve WSDL (IP:portname?wsdl) => ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

3) Add Service Reference in Visual Studio 2013
(http://user@password@ip:port,
http://ip:port) => unexpected error

4) Add Web Reference in Visual Studio 2013 
= > The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.

5) Tried all types of connection in PUTTY => Server unexpectedly closed network connection.

Comment: Well, that's not very much information... ;-) Do you at least know which kind of web service it is?

Comment: no. as I said there's no any information. it's like black box and I should understand how to enter it.